# Unexpected identifier error on the chrome bluetooth API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bluetooth

I'm currently programming a google chrome extension using the bluetooth API (my version of chrome is chrome-dev, as the bluetooth API is only on chrome-dev). I get an "Unexpected identifier error" at the first line of this script (notify.js)

```
chrome.bluetooth.getAdapterState( function(AdapterState result) {

    if (result.powered == false || result.available == false ) {
        alert("no bluetooth!!!");
    } else {
        alert("bluetooth!!!");
    }
});
```

Does anyone know how to resolve the issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Chrome uses Javascript for its App API.
- Javascript is a dinamically typed language. So you don't need to specify the type of an object (Neither when you send parameters to a function).

---

So just delete the "AdapterState" part and the "Unexpected identifier error" should't appear anymore.

```
chrome.bluetooth.getAdapterState( function(result) {

  if (result.powered == false || result.available == false ) {
    alert("no bluetooth!!!");
  } else {
    alert("bluetooth!!!");
  }
});
```